# Why does the Kong Manager throws Network error when I try to add new services/routes?

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

[image: Kong Pods/Services/Endpoints][image: Kong Manager Network Error]We have installed Kong enterprise free edition 3.0.0 on Azure Kubernetes Service. Installation is done via Kong's Helm chart.

We are able to access the Kong Manager without any issue. But, when I try to add a new "Service" via the manager portal, it is throwing "Network error".

Attached the Kong Pod/Svc/Endpoints details and the Kong Manger error for your reference.
Can anyone please let me know what I am missing in the helm configuration

Please find the values.yaml below, used to create the kong API gateway

```yaml
      deployment:
      kong:
        enabled: true
      serviceAccount:
        create: true
        automountServiceAccountToken: false
      test:
        enabled: false
      daemonset: false
      hostNetwork: false
      prefixDir:
        sizeLimit: 256Mi
      tmpDir:
        sizeLimit: 1Gi
    env:
      database: "postgres"
      pg_host: "10.XX.XX.XX"
      pg_port: 5432
      pg_user: "postgres"
      pg_password: "XXXXXXXXX"
      pg_database: "kong"
      router_flavor: "traditional"
      nginx_worker_processes: "2"
      proxy_access_log: /dev/stdout
      admin_access_log: /dev/stdout
      admin_gui_access_log: /dev/stdout
      portal_api_access_log: /dev/stdout
      proxy_error_log: /dev/stderr
      admin_error_log: /dev/stderr
      admin_gui_error_log: /dev/stderr
      portal_api_error_log: /dev/stderr
      prefix: /kong_prefix/
    extraLabels: {}
    
    image:
      repository: kong/kong-gateway
      tag: "3.0"
    
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    admin:
      enabled: true
      type: LoadBalancer
      annotations: {}
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      labels: {}
    
      http:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8001
        containerPort: 8001
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8444
        containerPort: 8444
        parameters:
        - http2
    
      ingress:
        enabled: true
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    status:
      enabled: true
      http:
        enabled: true
        containerPort: 8100
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: false
        containerPort: 8543
        parameters: []
    
    clusterCaSecretName: ""
    
    cluster:
      enabled: false
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}
    
      tls:
        enabled: false
        servicePort: 8005
        containerPort: 8005
        parameters: []
    
      type: ClusterIP
    
      ingress:
        enabled: false
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    proxy:
      enabled: true
      type: LoadBalancer
      annotations: {}
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      labels:
        enable-metrics: "true"
    
      http:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 80
        containerPort: 8000
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: false
        servicePort: 443
        containerPort: 8443
        parameters:
        - http2
    
      stream: []
      ingress:
        enabled: true
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    udpProxy:
      enabled: false
      type: LoadBalancer
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}
      stream: []
    plugins: {}
    secretVolumes: []
    migrations:
      preUpgrade: true
      postUpgrade: true
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: false
      jobAnnotations: {}
      backoffLimit:
      resources: {}
    dblessConfig:
      configMap: ""
      config: |
        _format_version: "1.1"
        services:
          # Example configuration
          # - name: example.com
          #   url: http://example.com
          #   routes:
          #   - name: example
          #     paths:
          #     - "/example"
    ingressController:
      enabled: true
      image:
        repository: kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller
        tag: "2.6"
        effectiveSemver:
      args: []
    
      watchNamespaces: []
    
      env:
        kong_admin_tls_skip_verify: true
      admissionWebhook:
        enabled: false
        failurePolicy: Ignore
        port: 8080
        certificate:
          provided: false
      ingressClass: kong
      ingressClassAnnotations: {}
    
      rbac:
        create: true
    
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: "/healthz"
          port: 10254
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: "/healthz"
          port: 10254
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
      resources: {}
    postgresql:
      enabled: false
      auth:
        username: kong
        database: kong
      image:
        tag: 13.6.0-debian-10-r52
      service:
        ports:
          postgresql: "5432"
    
    certificates:
      enabled: false
    
      issuer: ""
      clusterIssuer: ""
    
      proxy:
        enabled: true
        issuer: ""
        clusterIssuer: ""
        commonName: "app.example"
        dnsNames: []
      admin:
        enabled: true
        issuer: ""
        clusterIssuer: ""
        commonName: "kong.example"
        dnsNames: []
      portal:
        enabled: true
        issuer: ""
        clusterIssuer: ""
        commonName: "developer.example"
        dnsNames: []
      cluster:
        enabled: true
        issuer: ""
        clusterIssuer: ""
    waitImage:
      enabled: true
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    
    updateStrategy: {}
    resources: {}
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: "/status"
        port: status
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
    
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: "/status"
        port: status
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
    
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
            - kong
            - quit
            - '--wait=15'
    
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    
    tolerations: []
    
    nodeSelector: {}
    
    podAnnotations:
      kuma.io/gateway: enabled
      traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
    
    podLabels: {}
    
    replicaCount: 1
    
    deploymentAnnotations: {}
    
    autoscaling:
      enabled: false
      minReplicas: 2
      maxReplicas: 5
      behavior: {}
      targetCPUUtilizationPercentage:
      metrics:
        - type: Resource
          resource:
            name: cpu
            target:
              type: Utilization
              averageUtilization: 80
    
    podDisruptionBudget:
      enabled: false
    
    podSecurityPolicy:
      enabled: false
      spec:
        privileged: false
        fsGroup:
          rule: RunAsAny
        runAsUser:
          rule: RunAsAny
        runAsGroup:
          rule: RunAsAny
        seLinux:
          rule: RunAsAny
        supplementalGroups:
          rule: RunAsAny
        volumes:
          - 'configMap'
          - 'secret'
          - 'emptyDir'
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        hostNetwork: false
        hostIPC: false
        hostPID: false
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
    
    
    priorityClassName: ""
    
    securityContext: {}
    
    containerSecurityContext: {}
    
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: false
    enterprise:
      enabled: true
      vitals:
        enabled: true
      portal:
        enabled: false
      rbac:
        enabled: false
        admin_gui_auth: basic-auth
        session_conf_secret: kong-session-config
        admin_gui_auth_conf_secret: CHANGEME-admin-gui-auth-conf-secret
      smtp:
        enabled: false
        portal_emails_from: none@example.com
        portal_emails_reply_to: none@example.com
        admin_emails_from: none@example.com
        admin_emails_reply_to: none@example.com
        smtp_admin_emails: none@example.com
        smtp_host: smtp.example.com
        smtp_port: 587
        smtp_auth_type: ''
        smtp_ssl: nil
        smtp_starttls: true
        auth:
          smtp_username: ''  # e.g. postmaster@example.com
          smtp_password_secret: CHANGEME-smtp-password
    
    manager:
      enabled: true
      type: LoadBalancer
      annotations: {}
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      labels: {}
    
      http:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8002
        containerPort: 8002
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8445
        containerPort: 8445
        parameters:
        - http2
    
      ingress:
        enabled: false
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    portal:
      enabled: true
      type: ClusterIP
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}
    
      http:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8003
        containerPort: 8003
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8446
        containerPort: 8446
        parameters:
        - http2
    
      ingress:
        enabled: false
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    portalapi:
      enabled: true
      type: ClusterIP
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}
    
      http:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8004
        containerPort: 8004
        parameters: []
    
      tls:
        enabled: true
        servicePort: 8447
        containerPort: 8447
        parameters:
        - http2
    
      ingress:
        enabled: false
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    clustertelemetry:
      enabled: false
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}
    
      tls:
        enabled: false
        servicePort: 8006
        containerPort: 8006
        parameters: []
    
      type: ClusterIP
    
      ingress:
        enabled: false
        ingressClassName:
        hostname:
        annotations: {}
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    
    extraConfigMaps: []
    
    extraSecrets: []
    
    extraObjects: []
```

Comment: Has the issue been resolved?

Comment: Used to get this error when my CORS plugin is switched on in the browser.
When we were working with configurations related to developer portal, we had to switch on CORS plugin to test custom UI requirements.

Comment: @Ponsakorn30214, this is resolved by opening the ports: 8001, 8002 in the same kubernetes service